# How do I use trim in PySpark 2.x?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Code is:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.select(F.trim("MyColumn"))
```

Error is:

```python
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.trim. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method trim([class java.lang.String]) does not exist
```

Is `trim` deprecated in PySpark 2.x? I don't understand why it's not working, when some other functions in the same namespace work perfectly fine

Comment: Try `df = df.select(F.trim(F.col("MyColumn")))`. Based on your error, it looks like it's treating the argument as a string and not a Column Name.

Comment: Thanks, that did it

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.select(F.trim(F.col("MyColumn")))
```